# SQL self join and aggregation

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with the following structure in postgres

Table path:
 passengers, origin, dest, date, month, year

I want to find the top 3 routes based on the number of passengers travelled on a route in a year. 
Total Number of passengers on a route (A <-> B)  = Total Number of passengers (A -> B) +   Total Number of passengers ( B->A )

What's the best / optimal way to aggregate the Number of passengers on a route, the table row count is approximately 150 million rows.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

There are two approaches to this.  One is aggregation and the other joins.

```
select least(origin, dest) as od1, greatest(origin, dest) as od2, sum(passengers) as numpassengers
from path t
group by least(origin, dest), greatest(origin, dest)
order by numpassengers
limit 3;
```

The other is a self-join.  If there is only one row in each direction, you can do this without aggregation:

```
select p1.origin, p1.dest, p1.passengers + p2.passengers as numpassengers
from path p1 join
     path pt2
     on p1.origin = p2.dest and p1.dest = p2.origin
where p1.origin < p1.dest
order by numpassengers desc
limit 3;
```

Otherwise, you need a self join and aggregation, so the first method is probably faster:

```
select p1.origin, p1.dest, sum(p1.passengers + p2.passengers) as numpassengers
from path p1 join
     path pt2
     on p1.origin = p2.dest and p1.dest = p2.origin
where p1.origin < p1.dest
group by p1.origin, p1.dest
order by numpassengers desc
limit 3;
```

I do not know which would be more efficient.  However, I suspect the top 3 routes by the sum would be in, say, the top 100 for each direction.  If so, build an index on numpassengers, and try:

```
select least(origin, dest) as od1, greatest(origin, dest) as od2, sum(passengers) as numpassengers
from path t cross join
     (select min(passengers) as cutoff
      from (select distinct passengers
            from path
            order by passengers desc
            limit 100
           ) t
     ) minp
where numpassengers >= minp.cutoff
group by least(origin, dest), greatest(origin, dest)
order by numpassengers
limit 3;
```

The calculation of the cutoff should just use the index and greatly reduce the load of the rest of the query.

EDIT:

If you don't have `least()` and `greatest()`, just use `case` statements:

```
select (case when origin < dest then origin else dest end) as od1,
       (case when origin < dest then dest else origin end)  as od2,
       sum(passengers) as numpassengers
from path t
group by 1, 2
order by numpassengers
limit 3;
```

You can repeat the `case` statements in the `group by`.  But Amazon Redshift lets you refer to column aliases or positions in the `group by` clause.

Comment: Aggregation method works. I need to find out how it's working - Thanks    The second query (self join method) does not aggregate over passenger count column to provide unique origin, destination pair with total passenger count. Query results in duplicate routes with aggregation not fully applied on passenger count column. -- Thanks for the response.

Comment: @SanthoshS . . . I think I misunderstood a small part of the problem.  The aggregation without a join is probably the best approach.

Comment: I tried it in mysql,postgresql and the query works perfectly. Thx. Least and greatest functions are not available in Amazon Redshift - any alternatives to get the first query work on Amazon Redshift. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If every route is used in both directions that should give you an answer:

```
SELECT (x.passengers + y.passengers) as passenders_sum, x.origin, y.dest
FROM yourTable x
JOIN yourTable y
ON x.origin = y.dest AND x.dest = y.origin
ORDER BY passenders_sum DESC;
```

With indexes on your origin and dest columns that self join should not make you worry. I see no way to avoid an operation of that scale to get the requested result.
You will have to add some kind of `LIMIT` to that statement if you only want the top X rows. I have no postgres experience on that.

Comment: the query does not aggregate over passenger count column to provide unique origin, destination pair with total passenger count. Query results in duplicate routes with aggregation not fully applied on passenger count column. -- Thanks for the response.

Comment: In defence of SebastianH, I also assumed each row was unique in each direction. After all it's not our data. I've updated my answer and this one could be modified the same way.

Comment: @AchimSchmitz Thanks ;) And this answer is exactly as far as I will go without deeper insight into the data.

Answer (score 0):

I think SebastianH has it right. As a minor improvement you could try the following assuming postgressql supports the `SELECT TOP` clause:

```
SELECT TOP 3
    FROM (SELECT (SUM(A.PASSENGERS + B.PASSENGERS), A.ORIGIN, A.DEST)
          FROM YOURTABLE A JOIN YOURTABLE B
            ON (A.ORIGIN = B.DEST AND A.DEST = B.ORIGIN)
          GROUP BY A.ORIGIN, A.DEST
         )
```